# Develop office 2007 addins under .Net V2.0 and VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, projects-and-solutions, office-2007

this is a serious problem I need to handle with

I need to develop office 2003 and 2007 addins, both with .Net framework v2.0

Our company uses VS2008, which only allows developing 2007 addins under .Net v3.5

Does anyone knows of a way for creating 2007 addins unser .net frameworj v2.0?

(**Using visual studio 2005 is not an option**)

Comment: Where did you find that information? It is not correct as far as I know.

Comment: The problem is as follows:
with VSTO 3.0 - office 2007 addins must be developed in .NET 3.5
That is why we use VS 2005 (VSTO 2.0), you can try for yourself - create an office 2007 addin with VS 2008 under .NET 2.0 - impossible!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office), VSTO version 3.0 can target Office 2003 and Office 2007

Comment: Already have it... It only allows developing 2007 addins under .net 3.5